# Angular js ng-options selecting blank label. when i select it not showing selected

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

When i am selecting from dropdown it bind into model but the label of selection showing blank.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-options="data as data.field for data in reportAnalysis.categoryFields track by data.id" ng-model="reportAnalysis.testData"> 
    <option value="" selected disabled>---Select---</option>    
</select>
```

Any solution Please help?

Comment: Please add some angularjs code.

Comment: Do you mean you are seeing blank when you select anything from dropdown?

Comment: Yes. i am seeing blank while i am selecting from dropdown.

Comment: @KrupeshKotecha.... Data i am binding in dropdown..  {"response":[{"id":178,"field":"Attachments","sort_order":1,"field_type":[{"id":178,"type":5,"is_mandatory":0,"conditional_field_id":0,"conditional_field_value":""}]}

Answer (score 0):

As per the data that you mentioned, your select statement should be **categoryFields.response**. Not sure if you have already set your categoryFields to hold response object directly. Also the data that you shared has a square bracket and curly brace missing, assuming it to be a typo error. You can check working jsfiddle link for more clarity

```
 <select class="form-control" ng-options="data as data.field for data in reportAnalysis.categoryFields.response track by data.id" ng-model="reportAnalysis.testData"> 
 <option value="" selected disabled>---Select---</option>    
 </select>
```

jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/caq0ne1d/27/

Let me know if this helped.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module("Profile", [])
app.controller("ProfileCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.reportAnalysis = {}
  $scope.reportAnalysis['categoryFields'] = [{
    "id": 178,
    "field": "Attachments",
    "sort_order": 1,
    "field_type": [{
      "id": 178,
      "type": 5,
      "is_mandatory": 0,
      "conditional_field_id": 0,
      "conditional_field_value": ""
    }]
  }]
  $scope.reportAnalysis['testData'] = {}
  $scope.update_data = function() {
    console.log($scope.reportAnalysis['testData'])
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="Profile" ng-controller="ProfileCtrl">
  <select class="form-control" ng-options="data as data.field for data in reportAnalysis.categoryFields track by data.id" ng-model="reportAnalysis.testData" ng-change="update_data()">
    <option value="" selected disabled>---Select---</option>
  </select>
</body>
```